# How to remane "Cancel" button in sales order view?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

I have to rename "Cancel" button to "Cancel Whole Order" in sales->order->view in admin panel. Currently "Cancel" button is being created in

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {......}
```

and I am adding some new buttons to grid as following

```
class AG_ABC_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View {

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->_addButton('button_id', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('ag_abc')->__('ABC - Generate All'),
        'onclick' => "pdfAllClick('" . $this->getOrder()->getIncrementId() . "','" . Mage::helper('ag_abc/abc')->getItemDataUrl() . "','" . Mage::helper('ag_abc/abc')->getUrl() . "')",
        'class' => 'go'
            ), 0, 100, 'header', 'header');
    $this->_addButton('delete_order_id', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delete selected line item(s)'),
        'onclick' => "deleteOrderItem('" . $this->getOrder()->getIncrementId() . "','" . Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("/custom/deleteOrderItem/") . "')",
        'class' => 'go'
    ));
}}
```

What should I do. I don't want to override the functionality.I just need to change the label of button. How can I override label.

Comment: I have seen some articles about rename/remove "Add new" button, But those techniques are not working for me.

Comment: If you just want to rename, try with translation files.

Comment: That's not helping me

Comment: Then, please elaborate, what have you tried so far, and what errors you are facing in that.

Comment: I tried to use '$this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper("sales")->__("Cancel Whole Order");' but don't know how to use it

Comment: Then I tried to remove it, so that I will create it with new label, I am unable to remove it.

Comment: That label comes from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View` class. If you take a look at it, you can see that the label is parsed via Sales helper. So, in case of just a rename, all you have to do is, create your own translation file and map the word "Cancel" to whatever you want. If you don't want that way, then you can extend the class and re-write the constructor and in there you can change the label of the button.

Comment: @Prateek You can see (in edited post) I am extending  the class  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View , here i am unable to do as you said.i tried to change the label, but can't do it. If you can help..!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33029/discussion-between-abdul-ghaffar-and-prateek).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Prateek  thank you man. You guided me to right direction. What I have found is that I was missing to add

```
$this->setId('sales_order_view');
```

in my class before rewiring this button. So now my class look like this.

```
class AG_ABC_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View {

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->setId('sales_order_view');
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    $this->_removeButton('order_cancel'); // Remove old button having label "Cancel" placed in parent class

    if ($this->_isAllowedAction('cancel') && $order->canCancel()) {
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to cancel this order?');
        $this->_addButton('order_cancel', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel entire order'),
            'onclick' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . $message . '\', \'' . $this->getCancelUrl() . '\')',
        ));
    }
    $this->_addButton('button_id', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('ag_abc')->__('ABC - Generate All'),
        'onclick' => "pdfAllClick('" . $this->getOrder()->getIncrementId() . "','" . Mage::helper('ag_abc/abc')->getItemDataUrl() . "','" . Mage::helper('ag_abc/abc')->getUrl() . "')",
        'class' => 'go'
            ), 0, 100, 'header', 'header');
    $this->_addButton('delete_order_id', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delete selected line item(s)'),
        'onclick' => "deleteOrderItem('" . $this->getOrder()->getIncrementId() . "','" . Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("/custom/deleteOrderItem/") . "')",
        'class' => 'go'
    ));
}}
```

Label of button has been chnaged from "Cancel" to "Cancel entire order"

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, so that the question does not count as unanswered anymore